# Inserting & updating array values in WP mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I can insert a single record from variables into a custom WordPress table using the following method:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->custom_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'clients';
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->custom_table 
        (client_id, client_name) 
        VALUES ( %s, %s )           
    ", 
    array(
        $client_id, 
        $client_name
    )       
) );
```

However, I need to import large numbers of records (manual and scheduled) via an API which provides me with an array named $clients with the following structure:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1234567
        [name] => Client 1
        [other_field] => misc
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1234568
        [name] => Client 2
        [other_field] => misc
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1234569
        [name] => Client 3
        [other_field] => misc
    )
)
```

I want to insert each [id] and [name] from the $clients array as a row in the table.

If the record exists based on the client_id column (Unique index) then I need to update the row in the table.

Comment: You can just `foreach` on the array and insert row by row... do you want to do a bulk insert?

Comment: There would be at least 1000 rows so I would like to do it in bulk processing 100 rows at a time.